# T-SQL : Fetch all Text before last occurence of Dash

Tags: text, return

I'm stuck on trying to fetch all text up to (but not including) the last dash.

I can find a solution for fetching text to the left of 1 dash (eg. SUBSTRING(@ID, 1, CHARINDEX('-', @ID) -1) ) and even say the second dash but the issue is that the number of dashes in my list vary wildly.

- Eg.
- ID
- ABC-DEF-GHI-001
- ABC-DEF-2
- ABC-DEF-GHI-JKL-00003
- ABC-DEF-GH-4
- ABC-123-DEF-008

From the above I would like to fetch, all the text to the left of the last dash.

- ABC-DEF-GHI
- ABC-DEF
- ABC-DEF-GHI-JKL
- ABC-DEF-GH
- ABC-123-DEF

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One trick we can use here to find the *first* occurrence of dash in the reversed string.  Then, use that index to offset a substring of the entire string, but taken from the original beginning.

```
SELECT
    col,
    LEFT(col, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(col))) AS col_sub
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    col LIKE '%-%';
```

[image]

### Demo